# Button width CSS won't change on mobile devices, but fine on desktop

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a button to have a responsive width based on the screen size. I've got it so it works perfectly when I resize a regular Chrome window, but when I toggle the display to mimic a device (any mobile device/ipad/etc.) the width of the button immediately gets much smaller. It looks the same even when I open it on my iPhone, so it's not just some weird issue with Chrome's tools. When I inspect the element, I can see that width has been disabled:

[image]

I thought there might be some CSS overriding it, but then that doesn't explain why this behavior disappears entirely when I'm simply resizing Chrome or even picking one of the devices with wider resolutions than any of my rules. I have still tried removing all of my @media rules and the behavior persists.

The button is pretty basic HTML, and it's not even wrapped up in a div that could be causing the issue (unless the fact that there's a flex box right under it could be a problem?):

```
<body>
    <button id="ranking-button" type="button" onclick="openRanking()">RANKING</button>
```

And all of the relevant CSS is here:

```
#ranking-button {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 20px;
    font-family: 'Black Han Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: black;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    width: 40%;
    height: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0em;
}

#ranking-button:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

button:focus{
    outline: none;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    #ranking-button {
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

I've also tried adding `!important` to it, and it then did work for mobile - but then stopped changing for any other resolution and was stuck at 40% all the time.

Comment: you want it like this ? : https://angular-euyzx5.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd given up on this minor side project, and then randomly realized what I'd done wrong while doing something completely different - in case anyone makes the same mistake as me, I'd managed to forget to set the viewport. Adding this made the CSS work:

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: I had this issue on my slider dots, and it only worked by setting the font-size to 0

Answer (score 0):

When you use a @media query, it does anything inside it when the 'rules' inside the brackets are accepted.

So, if you say that max-width:1000px then, if your browser is 600px then anything inside it will apply, if not, then it will be ignored.

For screens smaller than 600px, your normal @media css rule will be accepted and there you said width:40%, and you can't measure in %.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #ranking-button {
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that to design mobile-first your regular CSS would have what you want to display on mobile, and then you use @media to change what it looks like on desktop - how would I do that with max-width?

Comment: Do u mean that u want for mobile %40 percent and for desktop:200px?

Comment: if yes just put !important to your css

Comment: I've tried !important (sorry should've said) but then this doesn't let it be responsive, it just forces it to be 40% all the time

Comment: That's not working for me - I guess I must have something overriding it then although I really can't seem to find it anywhere. When I delete width 200px from the @media part then it looks fine on mobile, but it's as if the min-width property is somehow overriding it regardless of the actual width of the screen

Comment: What do u want for mobile device, what do u want for desktop device?

Comment: I want mobile to be 40%, and desktop to be 200px. Currently it's always 200px, even if I only set it to 200px @media. For some reason when I set the resolution to min-width 1000px it works though, which makes even less sense to me

Comment: than your shared code is correct . In jsfiddle previous comment  it works. so there is another problem in your css. Can u share your all css

Comment: here's the solution : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-euyzx5

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm giving up. For some unfathomable reason the code only works if it's @media (max-width: 980px) { , any less than 980 and the button is stuck at 200px. This makes zero sense to me but I'll try and figure out a way to make it work

Comment: Order of mediaqueries is very important. If max-width 980 comes from  your min-width 600 then  until 980px it is accepted ,not 600  one.